# How to find month wise data from mysql in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Just a small quick question,
I want to form the query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE MONTH( `birthday` ) = MONTH( '1999/05/19' )
```

Now while in my PHP function, I wants to perform same but I am getting this from post variable , after forming the query my output is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 'MONTH(\"1999-05-19\")'
```

I want to remove `\` from code.
My Code for the following is :

```
$birthday = $this->input->post('birthday');
$where['MONTH(birthday)'] = 'MONTH('.'"'.$birthday.'"'.')';
$result = $this->User_model->getAnyData($where);
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: This "select month("1999-05-19");" works perfectly fine for me in MySQL. What kind of error are you experiencing? Is the getAnyData function returning nothing at all? If yes, can you show us the entire query that is being executed?

Comment: it is giving me blank array in reponse.

Comment: To find the error, get the SQL query that is being executed by the php script then execute it manually in MySQL Workbench (for ex). You might see the problem there

Comment: have you checked query ? Its giving o/p or not

Comment: Same query in MYSQL it is not throwing me error, but is is not giving me proper results

Comment: "MONTH('1999-05-19')"

Answer (score 1):

use like given below may help you

```
$birthday = $this->input->post('birthday'); 
$where['MONTH(birthday)'] = "MONTH(".$birthday.")";
$result = $this->User_model->getAnyData($where);
```

Comment: by doing this it still give me slashes

Answer (score 1):

If the POSTed data contains backslashes, use PHP's `stripslashes()` to remove them: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php.

Answer (score 1):

Depending whether your string was enclosed by single or double quotes will depend on what you do:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH("1999-05-19")';
```

Should work. Also:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH('1999-05-19')";
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the single quote, you need to pass `false` paramete in active record.

```
$this->db->where('MONTH(birthday)', 'MONTH(YOUR_DATA)', FALSE);
```

So the query would be like:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('TABLE_NAME');
$this->db->where('MONTH(birthday)', 'MONTH(YOUR_DATA)', FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,Fetching only month.

```
 $birthday = $this->input->post('birthday');
            $birthday = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $birthday)->format('m');

            $where['MONTH(birthday)'] = $birthday;
            $result = $this->User_model->getAnyData($where);

SELECT * FROM users WHERE MONTH( `birthday` ) = '05 ';
```